# What is the 'predictive' element of machine learning

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics, analysis

I'm hoping someone with a lot more knowledge of machine learning can help me out here. I've been reading examples of regression and classification and I always seem to come back to the question 'what is really the difference between what this algorithm is doing and what standard statistical analysis would do'.

Specifically, none of the examples I read seem to discuss the predictive element. For example, when looking at linear regression the articles commonly explain the concept of trying to create a 'best fit' - the combination of a linear equation and then iterating a cost function until it reaches a minimum. Of course, throughout a lot of emphasis is put on a 'training data set'. No problem... but this is usually where it ends. At this point I can't see the difference between the above and the standard way in which one would carry out statistical analysis on a data set that was assumed to have a linear relationship. Presumably, future values here are 'predicted' from the equation that was produced when the cost function converged on a minimum - again, there doesn't seem to be much 'learning' here as this is exactly what would be done in the usual case.

After a long winded intro... what I'm trying to ask is how has the algorithm learned from the original training data? and how does this training set help with future data sets? (again, this is where I get a bit lost - to me it seems that you would give it a new data set and carry out the same task of minimising the cost function - however, this time you have a better 'starting' point but all of your knowledge really comes from what you already 'knew' about the dataset i.e that one assumed a linear relationship).

I hope this makes sense - it's clearly a lack of understanding, but I'm hoping someone can shove me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: The basic point is that most algorithms do not just approximate a linear function, but some general function. Some approaches don't even need a parameterizable function (e.g. regression trees). After all, Machine Learning *is* statistical analysis. However, due to the high-dimensional function space, basic approaches usually don't work.

Comment: Sure - but to me that still sounds like a numerical solution. I'm not really sure where the 'learning' aspect is coming from. How is the future prediction dependent on the training data it has been exposed to - i.e if I use 15 different training sets rather than 1, does this improve the predictability of my algorithm, if yes then how does it?
The only way I can imagine it gets better is that assuming all the data sets are of a good standard then each time you use a training set you're able to start from a better set of initial conditions for the next set (closer to a global min)- optimisation.

Comment: "Learning" in machine learning is just what a statistician would call inference. The major difference between the disciplines is more of a philosophical one: machine learning practitioners care more about predictive accuracy (see e.g. deep neural nets), statisticians are a lot more worried about interpretability, model checking, etc. A lot of the techniques are identical

Comment: The following blog posts adds more colour to this idea: http://brenocon.com/blog/2008/12/statistics-vs-machine-learning-fight/

Comment: Thanks Ben - appreciate that.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, there is no difference. Linear regression is purely a statistical method, and "fitting" would probably be more accurate than "learning" in this case. But again, this is usually just the first lecture on the subject. There many approaches where the differences are much clearer, for example SVMs. There are also approaches where the "learning" aspect is much clearer, eg using reirforcement learning in games, where you can actually see your system improve its performance with experience.

Anyway, the main subject of machine learning is learning from examples. You are given a list of 100 patients, along with blood pressure, age, cholesterol level etc, and for each of them you are told whether they have heart disease or not. Then, you are given a patient that you had not seen before. Does he have heart disease?? Most people call this prediction. You might prefer to call it fitting, or anything else. But the fact is, it usually works quite well.

Still, the subject remains closely tied to statistics, and indeed, you need to make some assumptions (to a larger or smaller extent, depending on the algorithm) about the underlying function. It is not perfect, but in many cases it's the best thing we have, so I would say it is worth studying. If you are starting now, there is a great online course, Stanford's "Statistical Learning", which deals with the subject from your point of view.

Comment: Thanks for clearing some of that up - so if I'm not mistaken the 'predictive' element comes from the fact you have historic data and you've been able to determine some correlation about what set of indicators make someone have heart disease. In the case of your example, if the patients have certain blood pressure, age and cholesterol this is usually linked with heart disease (take this as true). Hence, when you give a new set of data (from a patient) if these indicators meet a threshold then it's also determined that they have heart disease - this is the predictions I was talking about?

Comment: As you say - I think I need to experience some of the more clear examples. As I've only experienced supervised methods - which to me don't seem all that separable from more 'standard' statistical analysis.

Comment: It is not exactly a "threshold", it is a combination of inputs which might form any function. Also, do not think of examples as "historic" and "new", but rather "known" and "unknown". Prediction does not necessarily imply "future", but rather "educated guess". Anyway, things will become clearer in classification, which is a much more important subject than regression in machine learning. I really suggest taking a look at the course. PS: In general, if you feel your question has been answered, please accept/upvote answers to make it easier for other users to find them.

Comment: Thanks for that response - I will indeed start looking into that course. Good note, on the 'historic' and 'new' statement, that could be somewhat misleading.
Also, I did up vote your response.